# Creating MultiDimensional Lists during Parsing HTML in Python

Tags: python, parsing, multidimensional-array, beautifulsoup

With the help, I managed to correct my code in [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187151/the-parsing-of-html-files-at-the-same-directory-in-the-python/62196204#62196204) and enhance it to this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
from os.path import join
from click.termui import pause

BeforeFinalJob = []
TheFinalResultThatUsed = []
ListOfFiles = []

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.html'):
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            ListOfFiles += [thefile]
            with open(thefile, 'r') as f:
                contents = f.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
                Initialtext = soup.get_text()
                MediumText = Initialtext.lower().split()

                TokensToClean = [t for t in MediumText
                                if re.match(r'[^\W\d]*$', t)]

                removementWords = ['here', 'than']


                for somewords in range(len(TokensToClean)):
                    if TokensToClean[somewords] not in removementWords:
                        BeforeFinalJob.add(TokensToClean[somewords])
TheFinalResultThatUsed = list( dict.fromkeys(BeforeFinalJob) )
```

However, the list of files and the words are in the different tables. How might I get the result in the list[a][b], where list[a] are the name file and list[a][b] the words of file list[a]? Additionally, there should not be any doubles in list[a]

For example, list[a] == file
and list[a][b] == some word, which in the file

UPD: There is some HTMLs which is in ZIP file:

https://www94.zippyshare.com/v/vJgy2sk1/file.html

Comment: Add some data from files in order to we can run this code

Comment: @Viewed I have added the Zip file, you can check

Comment: Did my answer help you? Accept it

Comment: Yes, the answer helped a lot. Thanks again!

Comment: click button in order to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code makes the structure

```
'filename.html': {
    'path': 'D:\\folder\\filename.html',
    'words': [
        'one',
        'two'
    ]
}
```

You can access to data like this

```
filename = 'filename.html'
print(data[filename]['words'][1])
# two
print(data[filename]['path'])
# D:\\folder\\filename.html
```

Full code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os import path, walk
from pprint import pprint
import re

removement_words = ['here', 'than']
source = 'D:\folder'
result = {}

for root, folders, files in walk(source):
    for filename in files:
        if not filename.endswith('.html'):
            continue

        filepath = path.join(root, filename)
        result[filename] = {
            'path': filepath,
            'words': []
        }

        for word in BeautifulSoup(open(filepath), 'lxml').get_text().lower().split():
            if not word in removement_words and re.match(r'[^\W\d]*$', word):
                result[filename]['words'].append(word)

pprint(result)
# 'y2k.html': {'path': 'D:\\folder\\y2k.html',
#              'words': ['the',
#                        'digest',
#                        'rhf',
#                        'joke',
#                        ...
```